# A mapping from a lattice to itself

Tags: linear-algebra, co.combinatorics, ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Consider $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ for $n = 2^r$ where $r \geq 1$ . Look at the iterates of the following function $T$ from $\mathbb{Z}^n$ to itself.
$T((a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)) = (|a_1 - a_n|, |a_2 - a_1|, |a_3 - a_2|, \ldots, |a_n - a_{n-1}|)$.

It has been proved that when $n = 2^{r}$, then for every  $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^n - \{0\}$, there exists some $i \geq 1$, such that $T^{i}((a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)) = 0.$ This does not hold for other values of $n$. Note that, if $T^{i}((a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)) = 0$, then $T^{j}((a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)) = 0$ for all $j > i.$

Findings so far are the following.

(i)   $T(k(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)) = k T((a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n))$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

(ii)  $T(k + (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)) = T((a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n))$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, where $k + (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n) = (k + a_1, k + a_2, \ldots, k + a_n).$

(iii) Let, $S_{i} = \{(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n) \in Z^{n} : T^{i}((a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)) = 0 \text{ and } T^{i-1}((a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)) \neq 0\}$ for $i \geq 1$. Note that $S_i$ s are disjoint also their union is equal to $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

The questions that I have are the following.

(i) What's the maximum value of $i$ such that $S_{i}$ is not empty? Putting it in other words, what's the maximum number of times the function T needs to be applied to a vector so that it gets mapped to $0$ vector.

(ii) Since the function $T$ is homogeneous, notions from projective space can be borrowed. How could projective geometry be applied here?

Comment: Is $Z$ the ring of integers? What do the bars in expressions like $|a_1-a_n|$ mean?

Comment: They mean absolute values.

Comment: I understand the absolute value only if $Z$ is the integers. Further question: Furthermore I do not understand the definition of $T$. What is $a$ here? Which ``earlier paper'' are you referring to?

Comment: Yes $Z$ is the set of integers. Each $a_{j} \in Z$ for all $j = 1,2, \ldots, n.$ The earlier paper, I referred is the following.
A number-theoretic game
Prithvi Ramesh
Published in Resonance, January 2003, P.84-88

Comment: I have corrected the LaTeX.

Comment: I think the $a-2$ should be $a_2$?

Comment: btw, I'm not sure if the linear-algebra and algebraic-geometry tags fit here.

Comment: As far as I can tell, $T$ is not homogeneous in any sense that is typically used in algebraic geometry.

Comment: Whats the notion of homogenity in algebraic geometry then. Can you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: I am also not sure that the title is well chosen. This works over $\mathbb Q$. Does it really fail over $\mathbb R$? Another question: The answer  to your question (i) might be infinity: There is perhaps no integer working uniformly for all (integral) sequences of given fixed length $2^n$. 

Comment: @Roland: If one coordinate is irrational and the others rational then no such i exists. Hence, yes, this does fail over the reals.

Comment: That is not true in general : Take for example $(x,0,0,0)$ with $x>0$ arbitrary. Iterating you get $(x,x,0,0)$, $(x,0,x,0)$, $(x,x,x,x)$, $(0,0,0,0$ if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Then in fact I was mistaken. The question is indeed interesting.

Comment: Answer to the first question is not at all infinity. For example, take $n = 2$.$S_{1}$ is then the set of points with $a_1 = a_2$. The other points of  $Z^{2} - {0}$ are in $S_{2}$. And  $S_{i}$ for $i >= 3$ is empty. So answer here is 2. Infact, for  $n = 2$ this holds for $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Small update, for $n=8$, I found a few vectors of order 93, but none above. But, since 93 is not a power of 2, a multiple of e, or a value of the zeta function at an obvious value, I'm assuming the answer is infinity.

Comment: I haven't understood the 3rd line of your comment. Whats the definition of e and how "93 is not a power of 2" applies here to conclude that answer may be infinity.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is infinity for $n>2$.

Suppose that there is an $i$ such that $T^i(x)=0$ for all integer vectors $x$. Then the same follows for all rational vectors by homogenuity, and then for all real vectors by approximation.

But there is a real vector that never reaches zero. For example, for $n=4$ consider
$$
 (a^3,a^2,a,1)
$$
where $a>1$ satisfies $a^3=a^2+a+1$. The next iteration is
$$
 (a^3-1,a^3-a^2,a^2-a,a-1)
 = (a-1)\cdot (a^2+a+1, a^2, a, 1) = (a-1)\cdot (a^3, a^2, a, 1) .
$$
Note that it is proportional to the original vector. By induction it follows that the $n$th iteration equals $(a-1)^n$ times the original vector, hence it never becomes zero.

An obvious modification of this example works for every $n>2$.

Comment: I don't think for any $a \in Z$, and for $a > 1$, the relation $a^{3} = a^{2} + a + 1$ holds. Can you provide a real example in support of your claim.

Comment: Surely $a$ is irrational. The example is a rational approximation of $(a^3,a^2,a,1)$ multiplied by a common denominator (to make integers from rationals). For each particular approximation, the procedure ends up at zero eventually. But the number of steps needed for that grows infinitely as approximations gets closer to the limit vector $(a^3,a^2,a,1)$. Because this vector never reaches zero as the above calculation shows.


Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer though. I am trying still to solve the problem. I would like to get comments on the approach that I am following. The approach in nutshell is described below.
I am trying to characterize the sets $S_{i}$. Note that, any $a \in S_{1}$ can be derived from the single vector $(1, 1, \ldots, 1)$, by doing either $k + (1, 1, \ldots, 1)$ or  $k (1, 1, \ldots, 1).$

Similarly, any $a \in S_{2}$ can be derived from any of the following vectors by applying  $k + <the vector>$ and  $k.<the vector>$.
The vectors are (i) $(0, 1, 0, 1, \ldots, 0, 1)$, (ii) $(1, 0, 1, 0, \ldots, 1, 0)$ and all the vectors that can be formed from the vector $(1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, \ldots, 1, 0, 1, 2)$ by shifting the elements of the vectors by one position in the right.

This can be verified. Can we now iterate in some way this to come to a value of $i$ such that no such vectors can be formed and then we stop. $i-1$ then is the answer.

Is it a viable approach? Or am I missing something?